# How can I change the color of bibliography item when using biblatex with beamer?

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I want to change the color of the bibliography item to be black. I used the following code. How can I change the journal names to black color?

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibliography entry author}{{\texcolor{black}{#1}}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beamer has its own mechanism to control colours, so the following motto applies

[image: Keep calm and let beamer do it for you]

```
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
```

Same works for `bibliography entry title`, `bibliography entry location`, `bibliography item` and `bibliography entry note` (this field also contains things like journal etc.)

Comment: Please, where is the full list of these commands available? I wan't to change the journal name colour, link colour, etc.

Comment: Never mind: @samcarter perhaps you could update your answer to state that `note` includes all additional metadata (i.e.  journal, links, etc). Thanks

Comment: @JesseKnight Thanks for your comment! I updated my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work when using biblatex.  It has no effect.

Comment: @KeithB Works with biblatex: https://pastebin.com/2fWLBAyZ